# Does the angular velocity of a wheel affect its height in this situation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity, gyroscopes, precession

If there were no friction at all, and the wheel was spinning with some angular velocity in the initial picture shown below. Would the wheel stay perpendicular to the ground regardless of the angular velocity? (assuming it started perpendicular).

[image: Diagrams]

The wheel in a frictionless environment would apparently precess forever according to previously asked questions. But would the angle of its precession depend on $\omega$? Like would it will fall to an angle that is dependent on $\omega$ and to be truly perpendicular to the ground $\omega$ would have to approach infinity or something? If not it just seems extremely unintuitive that at very slow angular velocity that the wheel would not fall to parallel with the ground. If $\omega$ does affect the angle then what is the equation for it?

Comment: How have you attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: Not yet. Hopefully someone can provide some insight in the meantime.